# Calling onChange function supposedly built into ckeditor 4.2+

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor textarea (version 4.3) and a javascript function, requiredCheck() I'd like to call whenever text is entered into it.

Supposedly, this functionality was built into ckeditor as of version 4.2 as part of the 'undo' function, but I can't find any information on how to actually call and use it. Everything I've found by searching is too old to be helpful (painful hacks on older versions before it was built in.)

I believe this is the pertinent section of the documentation, but I'm not skilled enough with ckeditor or javascript to really understand what I'm supposed to do with this:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.event-method-on

Has anyone done this with the built in function in 4.2+?

This is what I'm trying now based on responses below but it's still not working. Hopefully it's just a syntax problem?

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="20" cols="80" ></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        filebrowserUploadUrl: "upload.php",
        on: {
            change: function() {
            requiredCheck();
            }
        }
    } );
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. And yes, I've cleared the browser cache, I know ckeditor is sensitive to that.

Comment: use this plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/onchange

Comment: That plugin is for up to 4.1 only and should not be needed in 4.2+.

Comment: If you want to get a notification on every change, then that plugin is still the best option. There are many changes that the "core event" is missing. And the best of all is that you can adjust the plugin to add/remove anything that you don't want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Create editor instance.
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );

// Attach event listener to the #change event.
editor.on( 'change', function() {
    doSomethingOnChange();
} );
```

Or even shorter, with the special option [`config.on](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-on) usage:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        change: function() {
            doSomethingOnChange();
        }
    }
} );
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/N6v8Z/

Comment: I can't quite get it working. I'm wondering if I have the right syntax since I'm already passing a bit of config.

`CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {             filebrowserUploadUrl: "upload.php",
         on: {
          change: function() {
           requiredCheck();
          }         }
} );`


apologies, apparently i'm also not skilled at formatting code in comments.

Comment: Edited original question to include more readable code for what I have based on your answer.

Comment: I added a sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6v8Z/). It works fine, so I you apparently did something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
   onChange: function (element, callback) {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.dom.element.get(element).getEditor();
        if (editor) {
          editor.on('change', function () {
            alert("Change");
          });
        }
        return !!editor;
      },
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't get that to work, but that may just be that I don't understand it properly. Can you provide an example that is within the context of my specific code above? Where the editor is "editor1" and the function I want to call is requiredCheck() and is declared elsewhere on the page?